# $a_{n+1}=(a_n+c)/(1-a_nc)$. Is it possible to make $a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_{i-1}$ positive and $a_{i}$ negative for $\forall i$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds, monotone-functions

> $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_n+c}{1-a_nc}$. Is it possible to make $a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_{i-1}$ positive and $a_{i}$ negative for $\forall i$? ($a_0>0, c>0.$)

I tried to decide the sequence $a_i$ monotone sequence. If it is an increasing one, we can't make $a_0$ to $a_{i-1}$ positive and $a_i$ negative. So, I tried to decide on the sequence as the decreasing sequence.

To make this decrease, we have to make $a_n+c<a_n(1-a_nc)$, $a_n^2c+c<0$, $a_n^2+1<0$.

This is a contradiction. So, the sequence can't be decreasing one...

Is there something else to do from here?

Comment: Uh... I think I did something wrong. Editing..

Comment: draw a picture of  your Mobius transformation, as $y = \frac{x+c}{-cx+1}$    for things like $c = 5, -5, \frac{1}{5}$

Comment: and, for real  nonzero $c,$   there is no (real) fixpoint for your sequence to approach

Comment: What do you mean by $a_0\sim a_{i-1}?$

Comment: If $a_0=\tan u,$ $c=\tan v$ then $a_k=\tan(u+kv).$

Comment: How can you make $a_0,\cdots,a_{i-1}$ positive and $a_i$ negative for all $i?$ Is $c$ allowed to variable as $i$ changes? Because otherwise, this is impossible.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I mean, is it possible to make $a_1$~$a_{i-1}$ all positive and $a_i$ negative for the given $i$.

Comment: That is not a common meaning of the symbol $\sim,$ @RDK. Just use $a_0,\dots,a_{i-1}.$ $\sim$ is used in very specific ways, and your way is not one of them.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  I can't seem to reproduce  your $\tan(u +kv).$ For $k=1$  I have   $\frac{\sin (u+v)}{\sin (u-v)}   $

Comment: $$\frac{\tan a\tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b}=\tan(a+b).$$ @WillJagy $\cos u\cos v-\sin u\sin v=\cos(u+v),$ not $\sin(u-v).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  thanks. I had something correct on one page, later on a different page I started with gibberish..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_{n} < 0$ for $n \geqslant i \in \mathbb{N}$, then
$$ a_{n+1} - a_{n} = c\,(1+a_{n}a_{n+1}) > 0, \tag{1} \label{label} $$
indicating that $a_{n}$ is monotonically increasing, starting from $i$. By Weierstrass theorem on the limit of a monotone sequence we conclude that $a_{n}$ converges to some limit $a \in \mathbb{R}$. If we take limit from both sides in \eqref{label}, then we get an statement of the form $1 + a^{2} = 0$, leading to a contradiction.